# Lilypond temporarily joining double choir staves into one

Tags: lilypond, choir

I'm trying to typeset a double-choir score with piano. Overall the score is set up as *Frenched Score*, removing the choir staves when empty, but handling both choirs separately.

This is a distilled version of my current state:

```
\version "2.24.1"

\paper {
  #(set-paper-size "a4")
  left-margin = 3\cm
}

global = {
  \key c \major
  \time 4/4
}

scoreASopranoChoirI = \relative c'' {
  \global
  %\separate
  \textMark "Choir I"
  R1*20
  \repeat unfold 10 { g4 a f c }
  \repeat unfold 50 f4
  %\join
  \textMark "Choir I && II"
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
  %\separate
  \textMark "Choir I"
  \repeat unfold 50 f4
}

scoreAAltoChoirI = \relative c' {
  \global
  %\separate
  R1*20
  \repeat unfold 10 { g'4 a f c }
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
  %\join
  \repeat unfold 50 e'4
  %\separate
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
}


scoreASopranoChoirII = \relative c'' {
  \global
  %\separate
  \textMark "Choir II"
  R1*30
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
  %\join
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
  %\separate
  \textMark "Choir II"
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
}

scoreAAltoChoirII = \relative c' {
  \global
  %\join
  R1*30
  %\separate
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
  %\join
  \repeat unfold 50 e4
  %\separate
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
}

scoreARight = \relative c'' {
  \global
  \repeat unfold 30 { g4 a f c }
  \repeat unfold 50 e4
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
  \repeat unfold 50 e4
}

scoreALeft = \relative c' {
  \global
  \repeat unfold 30 { g4 a f c }
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
  \repeat unfold 50 e4
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
}

scoreAChoirIPart = \new ChoirStaff \with {
  instrumentName = "Choir I"
  shortInstrumentName = ""
  \consists Keep_alive_together_engraver
  \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-empty = ##t
  \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-first = ##f
} <<
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
    shortInstrumentName = "S.1"
  } \new Voice = "soprano" \scoreASopranoChoirI
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Alto"
    shortInstrumentName = "A.1"
  } \new Voice = "alto" \scoreAAltoChoirI
>>

scoreAChoirIIPart = \new ChoirStaff \with {
  instrumentName = "Choir II"
  shortInstrumentName = ""
  \consists Keep_alive_together_engraver
  \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-empty = ##t
  \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-first = ##f
} <<
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
    shortInstrumentName = "S.2"
  } \new Voice = "soprano" \scoreASopranoChoirII
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Alto"
    shortInstrumentName = "A.2"
  } \new Voice = "alto" \scoreAAltoChoirII
>>

scoreAPianoPart = \new PianoStaff \with {
  instrumentName = "Piano"
  shortInstrumentName = "Pno."
} <<
  \new Staff = "right" \with {
  } \scoreARight
  \new Staff = "left" \with {
  } { \clef bass \scoreALeft }
>>

\score {
  <<
    \scoreAChoirIPart
    \scoreAChoirIIPart
    \scoreAPianoPart
  >>
  \layout {
    \context {
      \Staff
    }
  }
}
```

At some point, the two choirs sign the same voices and I'd like to display them together in a single staff.
To do that I'd tried to follow [the solution provided here](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/95103/19397) and I end up with:

```
\version "2.24.1"

join = {
  \set Staff.keepAliveInterfaces = #'()
}
separate = {
  \unset Staff.keepAliveInterfaces
}

\paper {
  #(set-paper-size "a4")
  left-margin = 3\cm
}

global = {
  \key c \major
  \time 4/4
}

scoreASopranoChoirI = \relative c'' {
  \global
  \separate
  \textMark "Choir I"
  R1*20
  \repeat unfold 10 { g4 a f c }
  \repeat unfold 50 f4
  \join
  \textMark "Choir I && II"
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
  \separate
  \textMark "Choir I"
  \repeat unfold 50 f4
}

scoreAAltoChoirI = \relative c' {
  \global
  \separate
  R1*20
  \repeat unfold 10 { g'4 a f c }
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
  \join
  \repeat unfold 50 e'4
  \separate
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
}


scoreASopranoChoirII = \relative c'' {
  \global
  \separate
  \textMark "Choir II"
  R1*30
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
  \join
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
  \separate
  \textMark "Choir II"
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
}

scoreAAltoChoirII = \relative c' {
  \global
  \join
  R1*30
  \separate
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
  \join
  \repeat unfold 50 e4
  \separate
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
}

scoreARight = \relative c'' {
  \global
  \repeat unfold 30 { g4 a f c }
  \repeat unfold 50 e4
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
  \repeat unfold 50 e4
}

scoreALeft = \relative c' {
  \global
  \repeat unfold 30 { g4 a f c }
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
  \repeat unfold 50 e4
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
}

scoreAChoirIPart = \new ChoirStaff \with {
  instrumentName = "Choir I"
  shortInstrumentName = ""
  \consists Keep_alive_together_engraver
  \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-empty = ##t
  \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-first = ##f
  \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-layer = 1
} <<
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
    shortInstrumentName = "S.1"
  } \new Voice = "soprano" \scoreASopranoChoirI
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Alto"
    shortInstrumentName = "A.1"
  } \new Voice = "alto" \scoreAAltoChoirI
>>

scoreAChoirIIPart = \new ChoirStaff \with {
  instrumentName = "Choir II"
  shortInstrumentName = ""
  \consists Keep_alive_together_engraver
  \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-empty = ##t
  \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-first = ##f
  \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-layer = 1
} <<
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
    shortInstrumentName = "S.2"
  } \new Voice = "soprano" \scoreASopranoChoirII
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Alto"
    shortInstrumentName = "A.2"
  } \new Voice = "alto" \scoreAAltoChoirII
>>

scoreAChoirIandIIPart = \new ChoirStaff \with {
  instrumentName = "Choir I & II"
  shortInstrumentName = "Ch. I & II"
  \consists Keep_alive_together_engraver
  \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-first = ##t
  \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-layer = 2
} <<
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
    shortInstrumentName = "S. I & II"
  } \new Voice = "soprano" \scoreASopranoChoirI
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Alto"
    shortInstrumentName = "A. I & II"    
  } \new Voice = "alto" \scoreAAltoChoirI
>>

scoreAPianoPart = \new PianoStaff \with {
  instrumentName = "Piano"
  shortInstrumentName = "Pno."
} <<
  \new Staff = "right" \with {
  } \scoreARight
  \new Staff = "left" \with {
  } { \clef bass \scoreALeft }
>>

\score {
  <<
    \new ChoirStaff \with { 
      \consists Keep_alive_together_engraver 
    }
    <<
      \set ChoirStaff.systemStartDelimiter = #'SystemStartBar      
      \scoreAChoirIPart
      \scoreAChoirIIPart
      \scoreAChoirIandIIPart
    >>
    \scoreAPianoPart
  >>
  \layout { 
  \context {
    \Staff
  }    
  }
  \midi {
    \tempo 4=100
  }
}
```

This more ore less works ....

[image: Show_joined_choirs]

... but it has two problems:

1. When both choirs are empty, the choir I & II staff pops up. Turning on remove-empty on the joined choirs staff make it disappear everywhere.
2. When only one of the choirs is empty, both choirs are displayed.

[image: Unwanted staves]

Bonus points for how show a text mark when both choirs are displayed joined (which is not when they are *ready* to be joined)

Comment: Related: [Doubling part's staves in LilyPond](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/118158/doubling-parts-staves-in-lilypond)

Comment: Thanks @ElementsInSpace, unless I'm mistaken, that's the same solution I've implemented, but it has unwanted side-effects regarding empty staves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.
The solution came in two steps, for each of the two problems I described in the question:

Problem One:

> When both choirs are empty, the choir I & II staff pops up. Turning on remove-empty on the joined choirs staff make it disappear everywhere.

The solution to this was inspired by this [message](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2023-01/msg00169.html) on lilypond-user mailing list.

What I did was:

1. Redefine my join and separate markers to be:

```
join = {
  \tag #'split {\set Staff.keepAliveInterfaces = #'() }
  \tag #'joined {\unset Staff.keepAliveInterfaces }
}
separate = {
  \tag #'joined {\set Staff.keepAliveInterfaces = #'() }
  \tag #'split {\unset Staff.keepAliveInterfaces }
}
```

As you can see, this is more or less the code I had previously, but now they're tagged so that when one is set, the other is not.

2. Use `\keepWithTag` in the choir staff definition to select the right variant of the join/separate definition.

E.g for one of the choir I

```
scoreAChoirIPart = \new ChoirStaff \with {
  instrumentName = "Choir I"
  shortInstrumentName = ""  
  instrumentCueName ="Choir I"
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-empty = ##t
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-layer = 1
} <<
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
    shortInstrumentName = "S.1"
  } \new Voice = "soprano" \keepWithTag #'split \scoreASopranoChoirI
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Alto"
    shortInstrumentName = "A.1"
  } \new Voice = "alto" \keepWithTag #'split \scoreAAltoChoirI
>>
```

(same for the choir II)
... and for the joined choir I+II

```
scoreAChoirIandIIPart = \new ChoirStaff \with {
  instrumentName = "Choir I & II"
  shortInstrumentName = "Ch. I & II"
  instrumentCueName ="Choir I && II"
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-empty = ##t
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-layer = 2
} <<
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
    shortInstrumentName = "S. I & II"
  } \new Voice = "soprano" \keepWithTag #'joined \scoreASopranoChoirI
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Alto"
    shortInstrumentName = "A. I & II"
  } \new Voice = "alto" \keepWithTag #'joined \scoreAAltoChoirI
>>
```

3. Make all the choir staves be remove-empty true.

And with that I solved problem one.

Problem Two:

> When only one of the choirs is empty, both choirs are displayed.

This was toughter to solve. The way Keep_alive_together_engraver works with the "remove-layer" property is confusing as it is used for two contradictory purposes removing layers and keeping layers and, in my case, I wanted to remove some layers but keep others.

So, in the end I wrote a little scheme engraver to achieve that:

```
% Define a property that can be attached to grobs.
% This properly will name a group of staves that must be active together
#(set-object-property! 'keep-with 'backend-type? symbol?)

%
% Use the keep-with property to replace the "keep-alive-with"
% list of a grob with the collected staffs that have the same keep-with value
#(define (keep-with-engraver context)
   (let ((group-spanners '()))
     (make-engraver
      (acknowledgers
       ((hara-kiri-group-spanner-interface engraver grob source-engraver)
        (set! group-spanners (append group-spanners (list grob)))
        )
       )
      ((finalize engraver)
       (map (lambda (grob)
              (let ((keep-with (ly:grob-property grob 'keep-with))
                    (keep-list '()))
                (begin
                 (map (lambda (grob-other)
                        (if (not(eqv? grob grob-other))
                            (let ((keep-with-other (ly:grob-property grob-other 'keep-with)))
                              (if (eq? keep-with keep-with-other)
                                  (set! keep-list (append keep-list (list grob-other)))
                                  ))
                            )
                        ) group-spanners)
                 (ly:grob-set-object! grob 'keep-alive-with (ly:grob-list->grob-array keep-list))
                 )))
            group-spanners)
       ))))
```

The engraver follows a similar pattern to the Keep_alive_together_engraver (see [code](https://github.com/lilypond/lilypond/blob/59902ff2002a79046ef413d198a79621081860d4/lily/keep-alive-together-engraver.cc)), acknowledges `hara-kiri-group-spanner-interface` to build a list of `group-spanners` and then searches through the list for values of a custom property `keep-with` that will tell which staves need to go together.

Final touches are:

1. Define the keep-with for each choir staff:

On choir I:
`\override VerticalAxisGroup.keep-with = #'choirOne`

On choir I:
`\override VerticalAxisGroup.keep-with = #'choirTwo`

On choir I+II:
`\override VerticalAxisGroup.keep-with = #'choirOneAndTwo`

2. Use my custom engraver At the top level ChoirStaff and after the Keep_alive_together_engraver

```
\score {
  <<
    \new ChoirStaff \with {
      \consists Keep_alive_together_engraver
      \consists #keep-with-engraver
    }
    <<
      \set ChoirStaff.systemStartDelimiter = #'SystemStartBar
      \scoreAChoirIPart
      \scoreAChoirIIPart
      \scoreAChoirIandIIPart
    >>
    \scoreAPianoPart
  >>
  \layout {
  }
}
```

Everything coming together:

```
\version "2.24.1"

% Define a property that can be attached to grobs.
% This properly will name a group of staves that must be active together
#(set-object-property! 'keep-with 'backend-type? symbol?)

%
% Use the keep-with property to replace the "keep-alive-with"
% list of a grob with the collected staffs that have the same keep-with value
#(define (keep-with-engraver context)
   (let ((group-spanners '()))
     (make-engraver
      (acknowledgers
       ((hara-kiri-group-spanner-interface engraver grob source-engraver)
        (set! group-spanners (append group-spanners (list grob)))
        )
       )
      ((finalize engraver)
       (map (lambda (grob)
              (let ((keep-with (ly:grob-property grob 'keep-with))
                    (keep-list '()))
                (begin
                 (map (lambda (grob-other)
                        (if (not(eqv? grob grob-other))
                            (let ((keep-with-other (ly:grob-property grob-other 'keep-with)))
                              (if (eq? keep-with keep-with-other)
                                  (set! keep-list (append keep-list (list grob-other)))
                                  ))
                            )
                        ) group-spanners)
                 (ly:grob-set-object! grob 'keep-alive-with (ly:grob-list->grob-array keep-list))
                 )))
            group-spanners)
       ))))

join = {
  \tag #'split {\set Staff.keepAliveInterfaces = #'() }
  \tag #'joined {\unset Staff.keepAliveInterfaces }
}
separate = {
  \tag #'joined {\set Staff.keepAliveInterfaces = #'() }
  \tag #'split {\unset Staff.keepAliveInterfaces }
}

\paper {
  #(set-paper-size "a4")
  left-margin = 3\cm
}

global = {
  \key c \major
  \time 4/4
}

scoreASopranoChoirI = \relative c'' {
  \global
  \separate
  \textMark "Choir I"
  R1*20
  \repeat unfold 10 { g4 a f c }
  \repeat unfold 50 f4
  \join
  \textMark "Choir I && II"
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
  \separate
  \textMark "Choir I"
  \repeat unfold 50 f4
}

scoreAAltoChoirI = \relative c' {
  \global
  \separate
  R1*20
  \repeat unfold 10 { g'4 a f c }
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
  \join
  \repeat unfold 50 e'4
  \separate
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
}


scoreASopranoChoirII = \relative c'' {
  \global
  \separate
  \textMark "Choir II"
  R1*30
  %\repeat unfold 50 a4
  \repeat unfold 50 r4
  \join
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
  \separate
  \textMark "Choir II"
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
}

scoreAAltoChoirII = \relative c' {
  \global
  \join
  R1*30
  \separate
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
  \join
  \repeat unfold 50 e4
  \separate
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
}

scoreARight = \relative c'' {
  \global
  \repeat unfold 30 { g4 a f c }
  \repeat unfold 50 e4
  \repeat unfold 50 c4
  \repeat unfold 50 e4
}

scoreALeft = \relative c' {
  \global
  \repeat unfold 30 { g4 a f c }
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
  \repeat unfold 50 e4
  \repeat unfold 50 a4
}

scoreAChoirIPart = \new ChoirStaff \with {
  instrumentName = "Choir I"
  shortInstrumentName = ""  
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-empty = ##t
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-layer = 1
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.keep-with = #'choirOne
} <<
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
    shortInstrumentName = "S.1"
  } \new Voice = "soprano" \keepWithTag #'split \scoreASopranoChoirI
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Alto"
    shortInstrumentName = "A.1"
  } \new Voice = "alto" \keepWithTag #'split \scoreAAltoChoirI
>>

scoreAChoirIIPart = \new ChoirStaff \with {
  instrumentName = "Choir II"
  shortInstrumentName = ""
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-empty = ##t
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-layer = 1
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.keep-with = #'choirTwo
} <<
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
    shortInstrumentName = "S.2"
  } \new Voice = "soprano" \keepWithTag #'split \scoreASopranoChoirII
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Alto"
    shortInstrumentName = "A.2"
  } \new Voice = "alto" \keepWithTag #'split \scoreAAltoChoirII
>>

scoreAChoirIandIIPart = \new ChoirStaff \with {
  instrumentName = "Choir I & II"
  shortInstrumentName = "Ch. I & II"
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-empty = ##t
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-layer = 2
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.keep-with = #'choirOneAndTwo
} <<
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
    shortInstrumentName = "S. I & II"
  } \new Voice = "soprano" \keepWithTag #'joined \scoreASopranoChoirI
  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Alto"
    shortInstrumentName = "A. I & II"
  } \new Voice = "alto" \keepWithTag #'joined \scoreAAltoChoirI
>>

scoreAPianoPart = \new PianoStaff \with {
  instrumentName = "Piano"
  shortInstrumentName = "Pno."
} <<
  \new Staff = "right" \with {
  } \scoreARight
  \new Staff = "left" \with {
  } { \clef bass \scoreALeft }
>>

\layout {
  \context {
    \Staff
  }
}


\score {
  <<
    \new ChoirStaff \with {
      \consists Keep_alive_together_engraver
      \consists #keep-with-engraver
    }
    <<
      \set ChoirStaff.systemStartDelimiter = #'SystemStartBar
      \scoreAChoirIPart
      \scoreAChoirIIPart
      \scoreAChoirIandIIPart
    >>
    \scoreAPianoPart
  >>
  \layout {
  }
}
```

[image: Page1]
[image: from Page2]